# Projection operators onto convex subset decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space and there are closed convex sets $C,D \subset H$ such that every $h \in H$ can be written as $h= c + d$ where $c \in C$ and $d \in D$.

Denote by $P_C$ the orthogonal projection onto the subset $C$. It is not true that
$$h=P_{C}(h) + P_{D}(h)$$
in general, is it? Are there some conditions under which it is true?

Comment: If $C$ and $D$ are complementary subspaces of $H$, then it is true that $h=P_{C}(h)+P_{D}(h)$ and moreover that this decomposition is unique with respect to $C$ and $D$.

Comment: If you take $C=D=H$ then this would give $h=2h$.

Comment: @JWP_HTX You mean the point is they need to be subspaces and not only sets?

Comment: Even in the plane this does not hold. Take $C$ to be the span of $e_1$, $D$ to be the span of $e_1+e_2$.

Comment: @copper.hat OK but it holds eg $H=L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $C=\{h \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) : h \geq 0 a.e.\}$ and $D=-C$

Comment: @math_guy yes, $C$ and $D$ need to be closed subspaces that complement each other in $H$ (i.e. $H=C+D$ and $C\cap D=\{0\}$). The condition that they are complemented avoids the issues that copper.hat is pointing out. I am not sure if there are sufficient conditions for the non-subspace case.

Comment: Interesting question.

Comment: I would surmise that the latter condition holds for all $h$ **iff** $C,D$ are linear subspaces.

Comment: @copper.hat But in my example $C$ is not a subspace

Comment: @math_guy I was wrong, you are correct. An even simpler example (essentially your example) is $H=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $C= \{ x | x_k \ge 0 \}$ with $D= -C$.